# Does Windows Vista support USB keyboard and mouse during initial setup?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, usb

Does Windows Vista in the initial setup support USB keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Usually yes, although in some cases I've had to enable USB Mouse/Keyboard support in the BIOS.